# ExpressionEngine AJAX Call - Template or Action ID

Tags: ajax, expressionengine

I am new to ExpressionEngine. I am working on doing a AJAX call that returns JSON only and trying figure out if I should do it by inserting the method into the actions table or by calling a stripped down template.

Template would look like this ... one line ... (in ajax.group/call.html):

```
{exp:ajaxclass:ajaxmethod}
```

This way it is simply a call to `http://localhost/ajaxclass/ajaxmethod/`

Action's Table:

```
http://localhost?ACT=1
```

I really don't like putting the act id in the URI but I have been told that there are benifits to do that over the template way like it being faster. Are there benefits to using the ACT= over calling a stripped down template? I feel like I like the template way better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using the action URL is that the EE template engine doesn't run when it's called, so it *should* be faster (less overhead).

That's about it though.

Comment: Makes sense. I like the template url better so I'll benchmark both methods and see if there is a significant difference. Thanks!